# Moore-Penrose Pseudo inverse

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra

I am using the code below to calculate the pinv of a 4x4 matrix. The expected output is not being solved. The code is from https://fractalytics.io/moore-penrose-matrix-optimization-cuda-c. I used matlab to find the answer I am supposed to get. Any help with running the code would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

// C++ program to find Moore-Penrose inverse  matrix

#define N 7

void Trans_2D_1D(float matrix_2D[N][N], float *matrix)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            matrix[i * N + j] = matrix_2D[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return;
}

void Transpose(float *matrix, float *t_matrix)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            t_matrix[j * N + i] = matrix[i * N + j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return;
}

void MatrixMult(float *matrix_1, float *matrix_2, float *matrix_product)
{
    int k;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        { // not j<M
            matrix_product[i * N + j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
            {
                matrix_product[i * N + j] += matrix_1[i * N + k] * matrix_2[k * N + j];
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Function to get cofactor
void getCofactor(float *A, float *temp, int p, int q, int n)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    // Looping for each element of the matrix
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
            // Copying into temporary matrix only those element
            // which are not in given row and column
            if (row != p && col != q)
            {
                temp[i * N + j++] = A[row * N + col];

                // Row is filled, so increase row index and
                // reset col index
                if (j == n - 1)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Recursive function for finding determinant of matrix.
int determinant(float *A, int n)
{
    int D = 0; // Initialize result

    // Base case : if matrix contains single element
    if (n == 1)
        return A[0];

    float temp[N * N]; // To store cofactors

    int sign = 1; // To store sign multiplier

    // Iterate for each element of first row
    for (int f = 0; f < n; f++)
    {
        // Getting Cofactor of A[0][f]
        getCofactor(A, temp, 0, f, n);
        D += sign * A[0 * N + f] * determinant(temp, n - 1);

        // terms are to be added with alternate sign
        sign = -sign;
    }

    return D;
}

// Function to get adjoint
void adjoint(float *A, float *adj)
{
    if (N == 1)
    {
        adj[0] = 1;
        return;
    }

    // temp is used to store cofactors
    int sign = 1;
    float temp[N * N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            // Get cofactor
            getCofactor(A, temp, i, j, N);

            // sign of adj positive if sum of row
            // and column indexes is even.
            sign = ((i + j) % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;

            // Interchanging rows and columns to get the
            // transpose of the cofactor matrix
            adj[j * N + i] = (sign) * (determinant(temp, N - 1));
        }
    }
}

// Function to calculate and store inverse, returns false if
// matrix is singular
bool inverse(float *A, float *inverse)
{
    // Find determinant of A[][]
    int det = determinant(A, N);
    if (det == 0)
    {
        cout << "Singular matrix, can't find its inverse";
        return false;
    }

    // Find adjoint
    float adj[N * N];
    adjoint(A, adj);

    // Find Inverse using formula "inverse(A) = adj(A)/det(A)"
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            inverse[i * N + j] = adj[i * N + j] / float(det);

    return true;
}

// Generic function to display the matrix. We use it to display
// both adjoin and inverse. adjoin is integer matrix and inverse
// is a float.
template <class T>
void display(T *A)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cout << A[i * N + j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
    float A[N][N] = {{
                         0,
                         0,
                         0,
                         0,
                     },
                     {0, 2, 1, 2},
                     {2, 1, 0, 1},
                     {2, 0, 1, 4}};
    ;

    float *matrix = new float[N * N];
    float *t_matrix = new float[N * N];
    float *matrix_mult = new float[N * N];
    float *pseudoinverse = new float[N * N];
    float *adj = new float[N * N]; // To store adjoint
    float *inv = new float[N * N]; // To store inverse

    Transpose(matrix, t_matrix);
    cout << "\nThe Transpose is :\n";
    display(t_matrix);

    cout << "The product of the matrix is: " << endl;
    MatrixMult(t_matrix, matrix, matrix_mult);
    display(matrix_mult);

    cout << "\nThe Inverse is :\n";
    if (inverse(matrix_mult, inv))
        display(inv);

    MatrixMult(inv, t_matrix, pseudoinverse);
    cout << "\nThe Monroe-penrose inverse is :\n";
    display(pseudoinverse);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
The Transpose is :
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
The product of the matrix is: 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

The Inverse is :
Singular matrix, can't find its inverse
The Monroe-penrose inverse is :
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The expected pinv result:

```
-0.000000 -0.217949 0.461539 0.012820
-0.000000 0.358974 0.269231 -0.256410
0.000000 0.128205 -0.153846 0.051282
0.000000 0.076923 -0.192308 0.230769
```

edit 1:
actual output:

```
The Transpose is :
2.33793e-37 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
1.60717e-38 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
The product of the matrix is:
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

The Inverse is :
Singular matrix, can't find its inverse
The Monroe-penrose inverse is :
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I realized I did not change the #define N from the original code, I have updated that in my edit.

Comment: Where is `A` ever used?

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that they missed to call

```
Trans_2D_1D(A,matrix);
```

`A` is initialized but never used. Then the code continues with `Transpose(matrix,matrix_t)` but `matrix` is not initialized.

I suppose the code is mainly for illustration. It does each step seperately and displays the result after each single step. With a bit of index juggling, the 2d to 1d transformation, the transposing and calculating the inverse can be done all at once.